# Remove entry from Microsoft Word Navigation Pane

Tags: microsoft-word

I've got Word 2010 and when I open an older document, the navigation pane contains my table of contents, how do I remove this from the navigation pane?

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/table-of-contents-appears-in-navigation-pane-2010/af544a80-bea4-420e-a90d-8e67218b87a5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigate to the `Home` tab and the `Styles` group, click on the `Styles` pane dialog launcher (the small icon on the group name line).

At the bottom of the `Styles` pane there are 3 buttons, click on the middle one, `Style inspector`. In the `Style inspector` dialog, again there are 3 buttons at the bottom. Click on the first one, `Reveal Formatting`.

This displays the `Reveal Formatting` pane, which shows all of the formatting used on the style. As you click on a paragraph you will see all of the formatting.  So use it to look at the TOC styles and see if anything in the style is triggering the navigation pane.

Comment: In my case it was a problem with my `Outline Level` being set to `Level 1` instead of `Body Text`. But I do not know if this is a specific issue.